# Параметризованный метод Java

Tags: java, классы, generics

Всем добрый день!

Есть вот такая структура классов:

```
public class A {
    private String name;
}


public class B extends A{
    private String name = "B";
    public B(){
        //doing smth in class B
    }
}

public class C extends A{
    private String name = "C";
    public C(){
       // doing smth in class C
    }
}
```

И еще много подобных классов-наследников от класса `А`.

Мне нужно сделать метод, который прогонял бы определенный набор тестов для передаваемого класса-наследника `А`. Кроме того, для каждого теста должен создаваться отдельный экземпляр этого класса.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
private static <T extends A> void testing(Class <T> type) {
  T letter = type.newInstance();
}
```

Ну и вызывается так:

```
testing(B.class);
```

А как будет выглядеть синтаксис, когда я хочу передавать не один тип `A`, а, например, массив типов? Как тогда вызвать метод?

```
private static <T extends A> void testing(Class <T>[] type) {
   T letter = type.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Передать в метод массив? В чем проблема то?

Comment: @Vartlok, это понятно, только вот синтаксис непонятен - как именно это написать..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял твой вопрос, то тебе надо писать что-то типа такого:

```
testing(new Class[] {B.class, C.class});
```

Про работу с массивами в Jave ты можешь прочитать [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Про то как работать с массивами в циклах можешь посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687310/java-array-with-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать varargs и написать вот так:

```
private static <T extends A> void testing(Class<T>... type) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        for (Class<T> clazz : type) {
            T letter = clazz.newInstance();
        }
}
```

А в коде вызывать потом:

```
testing(B.class, C.class)
```